# How can we use 'if...else' in asp.net on front-end

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string

I want to use front-end code in an asp.net 4.0v form. Here is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
if(Request.Params["store"].ToString() == "Store")
{
<video src='<%# "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + Eval("id") %>' 
width="900" height="400" controls="" preload=""></video>
}
else if (Request.Params["video"].ToString() == "Videos")
{
<video src='<%# "Handler.ashx?id=" + Eval("id") %>' 
width="900" height="400" controls="" preload=""></video>
}
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to play video as a condition of query string. How can I do this in front-end 
code? Please help me with it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the parameter as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>

<video src='<%# GetVideoHandler(Eval("id")) %>' 
width="900" height="400" controls="" preload=""></video>


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then have a function to handle the conditional:

```
protected string GetVideoHandler(int videoId)
{
    if (....)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a function in code behind page which takes the query string as parameter and return your desired string i.e Handler.aspx or VideoHandler.aspx

code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>

<video src='<%# "Handler.ashx?id=" + Eval("id") %>'  width="900" height="400" controls="" preload=""></video>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now  Write a function on the code behind page

```
protected string myFunction(String id)
{
if (Request.Params["store"].ToString() == "Store")
{
    return ("VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + id)
}else if(Request.Params["store"].ToString() == "Videos")
{
  return ("Handler.ashx?id=" + id)
}
```

}